# jQuery select elements generated by a php script

Tags: jquery, regex

I have multiple `<select id="direction_X"></select>` generated by my php script. X is its ID. I am trying to select those  elements by doing so:

```
$('select[id*="direction_"]').live('change', function() {
     selected = $('select[id*="direction_"] option:selected');
     option_ID = $(selected).val();

     console.log(option_ID);
}
```

In fact, when I use  I am getting the option_ID, but if I try to use any other  I am getting the same option_ID from  all the time.

If you click  first, it gives you *(an empty string)* and when you click  after it gives you the correct ID from the first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `this` keyword which refers to the current select element.

```
$('select[id^="direction_"]').on('change', function() {
     var selected = $(this).val(); // this.value
     console.log(selected);
})
```

Note that `live` method is deprecated, you can use `on` method instead, if the select elements are generated by php, there is no need to use event delegation, in case that elements are generated after page is loaded, the correct way of delegating event using `on` method is:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[id^="direction_"]', function() {
```

[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
| [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to get all of the selected values then you'll have to iterate over all of your select elements and build an array of all the selected options.

Given this HTML -

```
<select id="sel_1">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    ...
</select>
<select id="sel_2">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    ...
</select>
<select id="sel_3">
    ...
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
</select>
```

You would do something like this to collect all of the selected elements -

```
var selValues = $("select[id*='sel'] option:selected").map(function(){
  return $(this).val();
});
console.log(selValues); // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

#### [Here is a quick demo (open your console)](http://jsfiddle.net/JdUnP/2/)